# Triggering long running operations from within a Linux ISR

Tags: linux, sleep, isr

I have a situation in which I need to set some GPIOs inside an ISR, then wait for 10s and do something else. Sleeping inside an ISR is not something that should ever be done typically. I'm wondering if there is a built in mechanism in Linux to enqueue a function (from within the ISR) for later processing by the user space worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Device Drivers. Chapter 10. Top and Bottom Halves.

https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/